# Best way to create user content management pages

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I'm currently building out a Drupal site that is an aggregate of local housing rentals. I have a user role called 'Property Owners' who have permission to add a content-type 'Property Listing' which is searchable by all users.

I am wondering what the best way to create a page where 'Property Owners' can view all of their personal listings as a link list (essentially a 'Manage Property Listings' page). I know that I can use the Views module to display a list of content based on content-type, but how do I make only the content authored by the logged-in user appear?

I apologize if this is a relatively simple question, but I've searched a lot of old topics and can't find anything relevant enough to help (also this is my first site built in Drupal).

I found the [Content Management Filter](http://drupal.org/project/cmf) module that seems to function along the lines of what I'm looking for, but it only has support for Drupal 6. Does anyone know of a similar module for D7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new view
2. Add "**Content: Author**" as a relationship
3. Add the filter "**User: Current**" to the views filters